# Changing CSS Padding Left based on Screen Resolution

Tags: jquery, css

I have a background image positioned here
batikdharsono (dot) com.
You can see the top left image is defined with this CSS code.

```
#top {
background-color: #000 !important;
padding-bottom:10px !important;
padding-top:10px !important;
padding-left: 30% !important;

background-image:url('http://www.batikdharsono.com/x_img/batik-bird.png');
background-size: auto 100%;
background-position:center left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

If screen resolution is 1024x768, the logo is positioned quite properly / not too far away from the navigation menu on its right.

But if screen resolution is higher such as 1366x768, the logo will be far away from the navigation menu on its right.

I've tried to use some jquery code such as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        if (window.innerWidth < 1100) {
              jQuery('#top').css('padding-left', '30% !important');
        } else {
              jQuery('#top').css('padding-left', '20% !important');
        }
     }
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any fix to my jquery code? or i can just change the CSS?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you doesn't use css media query ?

Comment: Is `top` the id of the according HTML element? Or do you try to change the css definition with `#top` (that won't actually work)

Comment: Use media query instead of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know media query before. It works :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just change css with `media query` like this :

CSS :

```
#top{
    padding-left:20%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){
    #top{
        padding-left:50%;
    }
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/9nk4hccn/**

You can also see more details about `media query` on the link of Luke H comments

Comment: See also this tutorial page: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
and wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries#Using_media_queries

Answer (score 6):

You can use viewport based units on your padding. Link to w3.org

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

```
#container{
height:200px;
width:400px;
background:#fff;
padding-left:20vw;/* viewport width's 20%*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nk4hccn/6/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id= "top">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="banner"></div>
        <div class="menu">Menu | Menu | Menu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top {
    background-color: #000 ;
    padding-bottom:10px !important;
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-left: 30% !important;
    position:relative;
}
.banner
{    
    background-image:url('http://www.batikdharsono.com/x_img/batik-bird.png');
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position:center left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
}
.content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:absolute;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**JSFiddle**
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/0scu38fk/1/)